# How can I apply the Elliptic Integral of the Second Kind on an indefinite integral?

Tags: integration

Within my integrals I have come across a situation in which I am required to use the formula for Elliptic Integrals of the Second Kind and since this formula goes as following:

$$E(\varphi|m)\equiv\int_0^\varphi\sqrt{1-m\sin^2\theta}~\mathrm d\theta$$

it only accounts for definite integrals. I have the following indefinite integral which I am trying to solve:

$$\int\sqrt{1-\frac{7933643041\sin^2(u)}{70433643041}}\mathrm du$$

and I can't seem to be able to substitute it into the formula to do it.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Also, I'm sorry that I wasn't able to implement the expressions into this post. I'm new on the platform so I don't quite understand the language of the mathematical expressions here.
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

By the fundamental theorem of calculus, if $f$ is continuous then
$$ \frac{d}{dx} \int_0^x f(t) dt = f(x)$$
which means that $ \int_0^x f(t) dt$ is an antiderivative of $f(x)$. Any other antiderivative will only differ by a constant. Therefore the general indefinte integral of $f$ will have form
$$ \int f(x) dx =  \int_0^x f(t) dt + C$$

You can apply it to the elliptic integrals as well. You have
$$ \int \sqrt{1-m \sin^2 u}\,du = \int_0^u \sqrt{1-m \sin^2 t}\,dt + C = E(u|m) + C$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Sorry that my math level is low. I see that many posts on the forum have sophisticated math. My question is how would I be able to integrate my expression with it being an Elliptic Integral of the Second Kind? I've got an indefinite integral here so I can't quite use the formula. Even if I did, I don't understand how I could get an answer as the answer is expressed in (|). So I suppose my question is how could I go about this integration? Is it even possible to do so? I'm sorry if you answered this question, I didn't quite understand the answer

Comment: @S_Orbital The elliptic function is the result of integration and it is the answer of your problem. You don't integrate it any further. If you hope to express it using elementary functions ($\sin$, $\exp$, $\ln$, etc.) then, unfortunately, it's not possible. Elliptic functions are called special functions specifically because they cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions. They can only be computed numerically.

Comment: Thank you very much. That clears it up. In this case I suppose that it is impossible for me to display and "integrate".

Comment: @S_Orbital To be precise, you can integrate $\sqrt{1-m^2\sin^2u}$ and $E(u|m)$ is the result of integration. You just cannot express the result of integration using elementary functions. But that is a common occurence with integration, the class of functions whose integral can be expressesed using elementary function is actually very small; it's just that these 'happen' to be the functions that are presented to you when you start learning integration, so that you could understand the concept.

Comment: Oh alright. I guess my final question is what exactly does the notation (|) mean? I understand that I cannot display the integral as an elementary function but if I were to express it in the form (|) then what would it mean for the values in it? Thank you once again

Comment: $E(u|m)$ is just a notation for a function of two variables. The divisor $|$ is used instead of more common comma beacuse $E(u,k)$ is usually defined as $$E(u,k) = \int_0^u \sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2 t}\, dt $$ that is $E(u,k) = E(u|k^2)$.

Comment: Thank you very much! you've been of more help than seemingly the entire internet.